# Prices missing tax i shopping cart. Corrects itself when visiting cart

Tags: configurable-product, cart, tax, shipping-tax

Magento 1.9.2.1

A really strange problem...

I only have configurable products in my shop with associated simple products. Product prices are entered without tax. Prices are displayed including tax on frontend. So far, so good.

Problem is when visiting a configurable product and adding one of the simple products to cart. When page loads the cart prices, both total and per unit, are displayed without tax.

Although if I visit the cart page (`/checkout/cart/`) or add another product to the cart, all prices are suddenly displayed including tax.

Because of this all orders are including tax as they should be. But when adding the first product to cart, the prices are displayed without tax, causing some confusion.

In tax settings I have the following:

**Calulation settings**

- Tax Calculation Method Based On: Unit price
- Tax Calculation Based On: Shipping address
- Catalog prices: Excluding tax
- Shipping prices: Excluding tax

**Shopping cart display settings**

- Display Prices: Including tax
- Display Subtotal: Including tax
- Display Shipping Amount: Including tax
- Include Tax In Grand Total: Yes
- Display Full Tax Summary: No
- Display Zero Tax Subtotal: No

I have also entered the shipping origin address in **Shipping Settings**. Address is in Norway if it matters.

Here's to hoping someone might have an idea on whats causing this.

Comment: With 'cart', in the sentence "When page loads the cart prices, both total and per unit, are displayed without tax.", are you referring to the checkout/cart page or the minicart in the header?